# How to give a member function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, std-function

I am struggling with C++ templates, functions and bind.

Let's say my class `A` is like this :

```
class A {
    void set_enabled_for_item(int item_index, bool enabled); 

    void set_name_for_item(int item_index, std::string name); 

    int item_count();
}
```

I would like to create a method in `A` like this :

```
    template <typename T>
    void set_for_all_items(T value, ??? func) {
        auto count = trackCount();
        for (auto i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            func(i, value);
        }
    }
```

So I could call it with a member function of A in parameter, like this (or something like this) :

```
auto a = new A;
a->set_for_all_items("Foo Bar", &A::set_name_for_item);
```

The three `???` would be the type of the second paramter. Since I'm pretty new to std::function, std::bind and templates, I tried what I already knew to use but I always got compilation errors.

So how to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for a standard member function is `Ret (Class::*) (Args...)`. In your case, this might look something like this (untested):

```
template <typename T, typename Arg>
void set_for_all_items(T value, void (A::* func) (int, Arg)) {
    auto count = trackCount();
    for (auto i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        (this->*func)(i, value); //note the bizarre calling syntax
    }
}
```

This will allow you to call with the syntax you desire:

```
auto a = new A;
a->set_for_all_items("Foo Bar", &A::set_name_for_item);
```

If you want to use `std::function`, you'll need to wrap your member function with something that takes the implicit object parameter using a lambda or `std::bind` or similar.

Comment: Your solution with two independent types is better for conversion reasons: +1

Comment: Perfect ! The bizarre calling syntax was what I was missing ! Thank you for your help. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allows me :)